# Vuex: Calculate percentage of values in array of objects, and update the value in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm creating a voting app using Vuex.

There are buttons to vote for each dogs. Right now I'm successful for updating vote number by clicking the buttons:

```
store.js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        dogs: [
            { id: 0, name: 'Dog1', vote: 0, percentage: 0 },
            { id: 1, name: 'Dog2', vote: 0, percentage: 0 },
            { id: 2, name: 'Dog3', vote: 0, percentage: 0 },
            { id: 3, name: 'Dog4', vote: 0, percentage: 0 },
            { id: 4, name: 'Dog5', vote: 0, percentage: 0 }
        ]
    },
    getters: {      
      dogs: state => {
            return state.dogs;
        },
    },
    mutations: {
      vote: (state, payload) => {
        const index = state.dogs.findIndex(dog => dog.id === payload);
        state.dogs[index].vote++;                
      },

    },
    actions: {
      voteAction(store, payload) {
        store.commit('vote', payload)
      },
    }
})
```

```
Button.vue
<template>
    <div v-for="(dog, index) in dogs" :key="index">
        <button type="button" @click="vote(dog.id)">{{ dog.name }}</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    dogs() {
        return this.$store.getters.dogs
    }
  },
  methods: {
    vote(id) {
        this.$store.dispatch('voteAction', id);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage of each dog's voting rate and update all the dog's percentage accordingly. I might could achieve this by:

1. Get total number of votes
2. Calculate each dog's vote percentage
3. Update all the percentages

I'm trying to implement this function in store.js methods but I don't know how to write the logic. And I'm planning to receive the updated percentages on Result.js

```
<template>
Result.vue
<div v-for="(dog, index) in dogs" :key="index">
    <div 
        class="progress-bar" 
        role="progressbar" 
        :style="{width: dog.percentage + '%'}"
        aria-valuenow="dog.percentage" 
        aria-valuemin="0" 
        aria-valuemax="100"
        >{{ dog.name }}　{{ dog.percentage }}% ({{ dog.vote }} votes)</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    dogs() {
        return this.$store.getters.dogs
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

How do I get all updated percentages from store.js to Result.vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider remove `percentage` from state data. it doesn't look that should belong to state since its value is derived from other state data values calculation. you could use getters for get a dog's percentage that like:

```
getters: {
    dogs: state => {
      return state.dogs;
    },
    percentage: (_state, getters) => dog => {
      const totalVotes = getters.totalVotes;
      return totalVotes ? (100 * dog.vote) / totalVotes : 0;
    },
    totalVotes: state =>
      state.dogs.reduce((count, dog) => (count += dog.vote), 0)
  }
```

now you would map `percentage` getter as well at vue component. Instead of calling `dog.percentage` you would call `percentage(dog)`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I could refer to other getter inside getter. I'm still a beginner of JavaScript, can I ask how  _state part work? I don't see _state used in the code. ```(_state, getters) => dog => {``` does this enable us to refer other getter inside of getter?

Comment: first variable is always `state`,  `_` is a convention way to tell a variable not used, but you could keep it as `state`. a getter function has an optional second argument `getters`, so basically all you need to use it is to declare it at your getter as `(state, getters) => ...`.  actually you could do `(_state, ({ totalVotes }))`, which would extract `totalVotes` right away.

Comment: That's very clear explanation. I'm still trying to understand ```(_state, getters) => dog => {``` part (maybe it's ES6 syntax?) but I'll figure out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have already resolved major part, please modify you store.js like below and check if it works.
Working example on netlify (css part removed)- https://dog-voting.netlify.app/

code on github- https://github.com/manojkmishra/dogvoting

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {dogs: [
{ id: 0, name: 'Dog1', vote: 0, percentage: 0 },
{ id: 1, name: 'Dog2', vote: 0, percentage: 0 },
{ id: 2, name: 'Dog3', vote: 0, percentage: 0 },
{ id: 3, name: 'Dog4', vote: 0, percentage: 0 },
{ id: 4, name: 'Dog5', vote: 0, percentage: 0 }
] , totalvotes:0,
},
getters: {    
dogs: state => {   return state.dogs;  },
},
mutations: {vote: (state, payload) => {
const index = state.dogs.findIndex(dog => dog.id === payload);
state.dogs[index].vote++; 
state.totalvotes++;
for (let j=0;j< state.dogs.length; j++) 
{let per= (100 * state.dogs[j].vote)/state.totalvotes;
  state.dogs[j].percentage=per;
}
},
},
actions: {voteAction(store, payload) {
store.commit('vote', payload)
},
},
modules: {  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never come up that I could create totalvotes in the state. But maybe I should write the logic in getters so that I could use the calculated value in other component?

Answer (score 0):

I would include my store.js data in Result.vue like this

```
<template>
 <div v-for="(dog, index) in allDogs" :key="index">
  <div 
    class="progress-bar" 
    role="progressbar" 
    :style="{width: dog.percentage + '%'}"
    aria-valuenow="dog.percentage" 
    aria-valuemin="0" 
    aria-valuemax="100"
    >{{ dog.name }}　{{ dog.percentage }}% ({{ dog.vote }} votes)
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        allDogs: "dogs"
    })
  },
}
</script>
```